# How can I add a video using Wordpress with full width in the page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been searching for couple of days now on how to add a video using Wordpress that will take the whole width of the page. I am able  to add  the video but it always show in its default size. What I want is something like [this](http://www.charitywater.org/pipeline/).

Any help  will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: how about css video{width:100%;}?

Comment: You might also wanna try video{background-size:cover;} But not sure if it works with videos.

Comment: please, show your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the CSS really. You will need to make sure that you are placing the video in a full width element of the page template.

CSS:

```
#full-video {
  width:100%; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<video id="full-video" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

If you have an example you are using it would be easy to help.